# Como bloquear adblock?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Estou montando um site que trabalha com anúncios e por isso não posso permitir que um usuário entre com adblock, tentei usar o script do www.antiblock.org porém só funciona em uma página, em outra pagina onde trabalho com navegação sem refresh usando ajax ele bloqueia a div principal e as vezes o site todo mesmo com o adblock desligado, alguém ai já usou esse script ou já teve esse problema?

OBS: o site trabalha com "troca de anuncios"(mais ou menos isso), eu não gosto de sites abusivos e que bloqueiam adlock por isso nunca usei esse script e não conheço, mas no caso eu preciso bloquear o adblock :D

Comment: Nota: essa é só uma opinião, e não tem nada a ver com o conteúdo técnico da pergunta, ok? :) Eu acho curioso como esse esquema de anúncios funciona. O desenvolvedor força um anúncio goela abaixo do usuário porque precisa do dinheiro, e o usuário procura formas de bloqueá-los porque eles são simplesmente chatos. Ai o desenvolvedor procura formas de bloquear o bloqueio, e eventualmente o usuário vai procurar formas de bloquear o bloqueio do bloqueio... rs Certamente há formas melhores de ganhar o seu merecido dinheiro. Se os usuários estão bloqueando seus anúncios, há algo muito errado com eles.

Comment: @LuizVieira, não trabalho com desenvolvimento de soluções abertas ao publico que necessitem de anúncios, então não sei bem como esse mundo gira. Mas o usuário não vai utilizar o adblock por causa unica e exclusiva dos meus anúncios, ele está utilizando por cansou de anúncios por todo canto de todos os sites que abusam deste recurso, então independente da forma que meus anúncios são apresentados, eles serão bloqueados!

Comment: @Fernando Sim, claro, mas é que a minha colocação era genérica e eu queria dizer que esse modelo de anúncios (via popup ou antes de apresentar o conteúdo) é simplesmente bizarro. Há formas melhores de exibir anúncios, mas essa é uma discussão pro [chat] e não pra ser feita aqui. :)

Comment: @Fernando só uma nota opinativa, é o seguinte eu tenho um site, os anuncios não são invasivos e nem atrapalham, mas o usuário já passou alguma experiencia semelhante em outros sites, pronto ele bloqueia todos os sites e eu sou prejudicado, então eu vejo assim, eu coloco um anti-ab em meu site, o cara é obrigado me colocar na whitelist e depois de navegar um pouco ele percebe que as propagandas em meu site não são abusivas... Outro site faz o mesmo que eu, mas as propagandas são abusivas, então simplesmente o usuário não voltará lá. Acho que nesse ponto o anti-ab é ótimo...

Comment: @Fernando ... Ou seja se o cara usa um anti-ad e tem um site "porco" ele vai acabar pagando por isto. Sou totalmente a favor das propagandas, desde que não atrapalhem a navegação ou invadam a tela e/ou funcionalidades básicas.

Comment: @LuizVieira leia meus comentários acima.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Tá, mas se as propagandas de um site não são abusivas, por que raios ele precisaria de um anti-bloqueio? Talvez o nosso conceito de "abusivo" não seja o mesmo. :) De todas as formas, eu reforço que esse assunto não deveria ser discutido aqui nos comentários.

Comment: @LuizVieira veja assim, eu forneço um conteudo gratuito, minha unica fonte de renda pra manter o site são os anuncios, detectar tais bloqueios é essencial pra que eu mantenha o meu negócio, não concorda?

Comment: Concordo com o @FernandoLeal . Por mais que a opinião do LuizVieira faça sentido o adblock é instalado de forma global no navegador para todos os sites. Para funcionar de modo que atenda os desenvolvedores que exibem anúncios de forma que não irrite o usuário, o ideal seria o adblock perguntar se o usuário deseja bloquear os anúncios do site em que ele esteja visitando.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Não há uma técnica 100%, mas há algumas recomendadas:

## Verificando o tamanho de um elemento

```
function detectAddNotLoaded() {
    if ($('.foo_dd').height() == 0) {
        // Aqui vc toma a decisão. Mostrar um aviso, redirecionar, etc...
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    detectAddNotLoaded();
});


<div class="foo_dd"><script>
//aqui deve mostrar um banner, mas o adblock bloqueia.
//A ideia é verificar a altura. Se for ZERO, possivelmente não foi carregado devido ao adblock
</script></div>

<div class="foo_dd"><script>
//aqui deve mostrar um outro banner
</script></div>
```

**Contra:** Um usuário sem adblock entra na página e os banners podem não carregar por alguma eventual falha ou podem demorar para carregar.

A vantagem em relação ao próximo exemplo é que torna-se mais consistente contra bloqueadores mais sofisticados que não bloqueiam arquivos pela nomenclatura (ads.js, advertisement.js, etc)

## Carregando um arquivo bloqueado

A técnica consiste em carregar uma url cujo nome seja bloqueado pelos bloqueadores.

A lógica é, a requisição ajax falhará pois o bloqueador impedirá de acessar "/js/ads.js".

```
   $.ajax({
            url: "/js/ads.js",
            dataType: "script"
        })
        .fail(function () {
           // Aqui vc toma a decisão. Mostrar um aviso, redirecionar, etc...
        });
```

O arquivo ads.js pode ser vazio.

Normalmente os bloqueadores procuram bloquear tudo que seja nomeado como ads.js, advertisement.js, e nomes relacionados. Então, a lógica é essa.

**Contra:** A requisição ajax pode falhar por N motivos. Pense no usuário que não possui nenhum bloqueador e então acontecer do ajax falhar.

## Considerações

Para ambos os exemplos, os pontos contra apresentam uma probabilidade pequena de combinações.

Os exemplos acima não são soluções definitivas e tampouco teem essa pretensão. Esteja ciente de que há outras formas de resolver (leia-se "chegar o mais próximo possível do desejável"). Os bloqueadores mudam os algoritmos periodicamente para adequar-se ao mercado tal como os anúncios também se adequam ao mercado e procuram se proteger de bloqueadores. É uma "guerra" constante.

Por fim, qual decisão tomar, depende de cada caso.

Avalie os prós e contras para o seu caso.

Comment: Perfeito, funcionou perfeitamente. Obrigado.

Comment: Ótima resposta, bem criativo

Answer (score 17):

Não existe solução técnica que consiga passar por cima de uma técnica que está ativa com privilégios no navegador. Existem alguns paliativos que costumam trazer mais problemas do que soluções.

O máximo que a pessoa faz é detectar que a publicidade foi bloqueada e tomar alguma decisão. Mesmo isto não é universal, pode parar de funcionar e não é considerado muito adequado. De fato já existem bloqueadores que não permitem os *scripts* da página detectarem se a publicidade foi exibida ou não. É possível inclusive ele bloquear alguma ação que impeça um conteúdo ser exibido porque a propaganda foi removida. Já tem bloqueador, ainda não "comercial" que inviabiliza a resposta aceita e a duplicata.

O usuário tem o direito de bloquear o que ele não quer ver, assim como ele pode fazê-lo em outras mídias. Forçá-lo, ainda mais em tempos que operadores de telefonia querendo impor limite de tráfego, não é ético e talvez até caiba intervenção jurídica se o fizer.

A recomendação é não fazer nada. Como toda proteção, sempre há como burlar, e o mecanismo acaba trazendo problemas para todos, inclusive quem aceita a publicidade. Quando alguém acha que encontrou uma solução definitiva, muito mais rapidamente do que inventaram esta solução, acham uma que acaba com a proteção. É uma bobagem querer fazer proteções em meio digital onde terceiros tenham acesso a todo contexto onde está sendo executado.

Minha sugestão é fazer a publicidade parte integrante do conteúdo, assim fica difícil bloquear. Mas ninguém quer fazer isto porque dá trabalho. Quer ganhar dinheiro fácil com publicidade? Aceite que ela será facilmente bloqueada. Ou procure outro modelo que não dependa dos usuários mais ativos que não aceitam isto.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 12):

Se o seu site vive de anúncios e não quer permitir o acesso sem eles, primeiro você deve criar uma política de uso e informar ao usuário.

Já vi alguns sites que mostram uma *popup* pedindo para você aceitar como que um contrato, dizendo que você não vai bloquear os *popups* daquele site. Você pode explicitamente sugerir que o usuário adicione o site como exceção no AdBlocker.

Em geral, como disse o @Maniero, não é muito legal você bloquear usuários simplesmente por usar AdBlocker. Por exemplo, se um site de notícias fizer isso comigo eu simplesmente vou para outro site.

Entretanto, se o conteúdo que você fornece é algo mais específico e único, pode ser que não seja um problema tão grande, afinal os usuários vão querer aceitar de qualquer forma.

Finalmente, considere que propaganda dá dinheiro se há volume. Talvez não compense o trabalho de bloquear o AdBlocker simplesmente porque você não vai ganhar dinheiro forçando algumas pessoas a mais a verem as propagandas. É melhor investir em tornar o site melhor, mais rápido, amigável, útil e relevante e assim atrair mais pessoas que além de ver vão clicar nos links.

Na prática, você pode usar técnicas de detecção do AdBlocker como na resposta do Daniel e executar alguma ação para não deixar o usuário ver a página. Mas como disse, isso vai exigir trabalho.

Uma forma é carregar todo o conteúdo via AJAX. Primeiro você carrega as propagandas e somente depois o conteúdo normal. Se o primeiro falhar, você mostra algum aviso para o usuário.

Comment: Acho que informar o usuário e pedir que ele inclua o site na *whitelist* do bloqueador é a forma mais amigável de resolver isto.