# Como verificar se o usuário está com o adblock ativado?

Tags: javascript, html

Tenho um bloco com html q é um anuncio, mas se a pessoa tiver usando adblock ele n vai aparecer.

O que preciso fazer é se o usuário não estiver com o adblock ativado o anuncio aparece mas se estiver ativado apareça uma msg no lugar do anuncio.

```
    <div class="Aside-bloc-0">
        <span>Propaganda</span>
        <center>
            <div class="propaganda">
                <a href="link_propaganda">
                    <img src="img_propaganda"/>
                </a>
            </div>
        </center>
    </div>
```

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/123884/como-bloquear-adblock

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como bloquear adblock?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/123884/como-bloquear-adblock), [Detectar AdBlock e exibir uma mensagem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/87961).